# ffmpeg on raspberry to stream to chromecast

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, cctv

I am looking for some help to stream security camera (incl audio) to a google smart display (Lenovo smart display, which has a chromecast included).

I am able to view, with VLC, the security camera, with the right rtsp link.

On raspberry, I installed ffmpeg, and I am able to run it to get a HLS stream, based on this article: https://www.reddit.com/r/Chromecast/comments/50o9yo/rtsp_streaming/d8pci0h/?context=1

```
    ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://admin:123456@192.168.0.218/live/ch1 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -hls_wrap 40 -flags -global_header /var/www/html/cam/cam.m3u8
```

However, this doesn't stream anything to my chromecast, and the link http://[IP raspberry]/cam/cam.m3u8 doesn't read.
It just creates 40 small .ts files in the cam directory (overwritten in loop).

I have tried to modify the last line as:
-f mpegts udp://[IP chromecast]:[port]

but that doesn't play as well.

Can someone help me ? I am not expert at all, I just modify codes I found trying to make it work.

I also have a nodered server on the rPi and I have been told I could use castv2 node to stream my m3u8 to the chromecast, but I have not seen any example so I do not know how to do that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

chromecast is not a server but client. You have to serve your stream, for example using ffserver, and then tell chromecast to connect to it.